# How to write a loop in a function in python?

Tags: python

Im trying to make a function that reads all the lines in a file and then prints out true/false for each line depending on if they have an "error" in the line.

I made one and it works for the most part, but it seems to randomly skip lines in the file. I don't understand why. If I write

```
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

then I get all the lines. When I do

```
def findErr(sensor):
    for line in f:
         print(line)
```

then I randomly lose lines.My boolean part of the function works fine though. it just won't read all the lines. I don't get why.

just incase here is the whole thing.

```
f = open("sensors.txt", "r")
def findErr(sensor):
    for line in f:
        sensorline = line.split(";")
        sensor=sensorline[0]
        if "Error" in line:
            Error = True
        if not "Error" in line:
            Error = False
        return(sensor, Error)

for line in f:
    (sErrors) = findErr(line)
    print(sErrors)
```

I also get a random "None" value at the end of my printout. Idk what this is.

Comment: You're looping over `f` twice, once outside the function and once within it…!?

Comment: Unrelated tip: It's standard to make all variables start with a lowercase character

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the lines both in your script and in the function. 
As you call your function with each line, there is no need to make this loop again in the function

```
def findErr(l):
    sensorline = l.split(";")
    sensor=sensorline[0]
    if "Error" in l: # or in sensorline?
        Error = True
    if not "Error" in l:
        Error = False
    return(sensor, Error)
```

should do what you want (if I understood properly)

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking to do thank you. It totally makes sense now, but I'm also confused as to why it wouldn't work if I looped over it twice. I thought it was redundant, but I don't see why it would make it break. I thought I was just being cautious.

Comment: I don't really know, but there was several issues with the code: You were calling the function with sensor, which is not really used in the function afterward, and acessing to line, which is not really define in the scope of the function (so I guess that the line used in the function was the one declared globally in your script)